# Error using Devise new registration on my rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am building my first rails application using the Devise gem for authentication.

The login works great but the new registration (sign up) page delivers an error on the PAGE and will not let me register.

See image 
[image]

Is this an issue with strong parameters or my application controller. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you filling all fields? Also, can you paste rake routes?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdj6m2ut9e8frdz/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-31%20at%2022.06.56.png?dl=0

Comment: Thank you for the response, my rake routes are above. Yes I fill in all of the fields with numerous details.

Comment: routes are fine, do you provide correct info in fields (i.e. email@example.com in email field and so on)?

Comment: Can you show us your controller?

Comment: Why isn't your code here, on this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you have [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) enabled in your `User` model where you specified the `email` and `password` can't be blank.

So, you have to provide `email` and `password` of a `user` when trying to save the info.

#### Update

If that's not the case, then it could be related to strong parameters. See [this thread](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters).

In your `application_controller.rb` file, add the following:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
end
```

Configure your other actions like above too.

#### More update

The main issue was in the sign up form as it was not using the form builder properly and was not posting the params. I modified the `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` file to this:

```
 <h2>Be cool and sign up if you dont have an account:</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Signup</h2>

  <form class="form-signup">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First Name", tabindex: "2" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", tabindex: "2", placeholder: "Password", required: true %>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password_confirmation">Password</label>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", tabindex: "2", placeholder: "Password Confirmation", required: true %>
    </div>

      <div><%= f.submit "Sign up", class:"btn btn-primary"%></div>
  </form>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

making sure the params are posting to the controller properly, and everything is working as expected now.

Comment: OP confirmed that he's providing correct info while trying to sign up.

Comment: Yeah, just saw that, but if you see OP's screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EnbSf.png there is clearly no values in the email and password fields.

Comment: You're assuming that he didn't fill in those fields when testing the page. It's reasonable to assume that he did fill in the fields and still received the errors, which is what he actually just confirmed to us in the above comments.

Comment: That just means he probably called `redirect_to` on a failed save instead of `render`.

Comment: yeah, that might be the case. Lets wait for his controller code.

Comment: I have only been coding 5 weeks. bear with me a second please.

Comment: No worries, we'll get this sorted out for ya.

Comment: I have filled the fields in. Irrespective of the integrity of the data that is put into those fields, it pumps out that error...

Comment: Chris, people are bearing with you for sure, just not with me. Already gave a downvote, lol. Anyways, please tell when do exactly see this error? When you click the `Sign Up` button?

Comment: class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end

Comment: Please let me know which specific controller you wish to see. I appreciate your help greatly.

Comment: The controller that corresponds to the model that this page's form is accepting data for, the model with email and password attributes

Comment: Also, post your `routes.rb` file too.

Comment: As per the thread. As soon as I have filled the fields with values and press the submit button

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzcrlylphx1snf6/Screenshot%202015-10-31%2022.25.13.png?dl=0

Comment: You screencapped this page, Chris. Please copy and paste the code to your original question. Also, did you happen to edit `application_controller.rb`?

Comment: I have 3 controllers. 1) An application controller, 2). A pages controller 3) Pins controller for pins scaffolding

Comment: Chris, see my update on my answer. Do you already that code in your controller? If not, add that and try again. That may solve your problem.

Comment: I never messed with the application controller Jason

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpxkkxqoq8xcchz/Screenshot%202015-10-31%2022.29.18.png?dl=0

Comment: See this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters
If you already don't have that, then use that code that I posted my in updated answer.

Comment: will try that code now. will revert in a minute with update.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmgumzjmrqufifr/Screenshot%202015-10-31%2022.36.46.png?dl=0

Comment: We're about to lose Chris, unless he plugs in his laptop.

Comment: Is this placed correctly in my controller, see image directly above. I tried this and it still does not fix it

Comment: Let's see your pins controller. Or maybe that won't help. I don't know much about Devise, actually, but I think we need to see the controller that contains the action for the page that is giving you trouble.

Comment: battery in. sorry. that code was bumped into my app controller and its still not worked

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmgumzjmrqufifr/Screenshot%202015-10-31%2022.36.46.png?dl=0

Comment: That's still `application_controller.rb`. Your comment contains the same image from earlier.

Comment: You also need this for `sign_in`, `      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation) }` updated the answer again with this. please try and let us know.

Comment: I'm finding this a bloody nightmare as i can't paste the code in as I am a newish member with not enough points, is their a screenshare I could do, I have join.me

Comment: Probably the best way is to upload the code on github and let us take a look by running it locally.

Comment: Chris- can you please screencap your pins controller and provide a link to the image?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/69gu27e8xh48hwx/class%20PinsController%20%3C%20ApplicationController.pdf?dl=0

Comment: jason see this PDF. Pins controller full code. thanks

Comment: When you navigate to the page that is giving you trouble, there is a line in your server's console window that says `Processing byXXXXXXXController#YYYYYYY as HTML`. What does it say for XXXXXXX and YYYYYYY?

Comment: Jason, are you wanting a screen grab of how my terminal looks when I try and execute this??

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uymheg6kl0mrede/Screenshot%202015-10-31%2023.10.48.png?dl=0

Comment: Ah, so this says that when you click the "Sign-Up" button, the `create` action in `RegistrationsController` is called. This is where you should focus your attention. This terminal output also shows us that your `password` and `email` values are not making it to the server, since they are absent from `parameters`. This might take me a while to diagnose because I've never used Devise and this looks like functionality that is built into Devise, but @KMRakibulIslam might be able to help since I think he has experience with it.

Comment: Could you please push the code to github so that I can clone it and take a look? It's hard to tell what went wrong exactly without seeing the full code.

Comment: Hey KM I have this on github already, How do you get a look at this

Comment: Just give me the link so that I can clone the project and try it myself.

Comment: taking a look, will get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: If you remove `:validatable` from the `user.rb` (`User` model), then this problem is resolved. But, then you can add user validation yourself.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam Devise hides your parameters? That's annoying. What does it do for you, anyways?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hp3knccbvvqcl45/Screenshot%202015-11-01%2000.17.27.png?dl=0

Comment: Well, you get a sytax error because you have a syntax error. Check your `user.rb` file carefully again. By the mean time, I trying to fix another issue.

Comment: If you remove :validatable from my file, I get a syntax error. as per the screenshot

Comment: Did you remove the comma just before it?

Comment: yes, should be just this: `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable`, so this will fix the current error. But there are more problems.

Comment: He didn't remove the comma after `:trackable` yet

Comment: Ok, so after you remove validatable the current problem will be gone. But, then the next problem is, your params (`emai`, `password` etc.) are going through. We need to make that work. But, seems like its a mess already. Why not just do it from the beginning again?

Comment: Gents, I am following video tutorials from one month, i am not a professional coder. only been coding 6 weeks and trying to learn

Comment: Thats fine. Could you tell me how did you generate the `registrations/new.html.erb` file? By following which tutorial?

Comment: If I remove the commas after : trackable it goes to syntax error

Comment: well, give me some more time. I am fixing the issue.

Comment: KM. I got help on here with registrations/new.html.erb

Comment: Yes, fixed :) I will push the code to your repo shortly :)

Comment: appreciate that. Can you let me know here where I was going wrong.

Comment: I cant push to your repo as I dont have access. I have updated my answer. Just copy and paste the content of the `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` file, and you dont need to change anything else. your sign up form is working like a charm now :)

Comment: KM. You are a bloody GENIUS>>>>>>> It works and i am grateful. Question for you though, did that go wrong as I was customising the form outwit the perams of its form control

Comment: Whatever customizing you do, you have to make sure that you are posting the user given form data, otherwise nothing will work.

Comment: I am still hoping whoever downvoted this answer would come and revoke his downvote!

Answer (score 0):

With what I can see, and what you explained:

1. `you filled in the email and password field`
2. `it went through your controller and then to the model`
3. `there is validation in your model that is complaining of the absence of email and password`.

*I am assuming that you are using the sign-up page generated by Devise (this is already set up to get a new user form, bound with a new instance of the User class).*

From the above three points (and the assumption), it stands to reason that both the email and password that you filled in are getting lost somewhere along the way.

My guess will be that this is happening somewhere in your controller. According to your routes, that will be the registrations controller (the `create action`).

Do you have a custom `registrations#create` controller? if yes => I think your params are not being allowed into building the new User which the `save` action is being called on.

If that is the case, you will need something like:

```
def new_user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

and then building and saving the new user as:

```
@user = User.new(new_user_params)
@user.save
```

Hope this helps to throw some light into it...

Comment: I have a app controller, pins controller and pages controller.

Comment: and what do you have in your ApplicationController ? have you confirmed that you have what K M Rakibul Islam suggested? in your controller?

by adding the `before_filter` for configuring permitted params? because I'm almost a 100% sure that the params are not getting through. Confirm that you have that.

Comment: Can you show what you have in the ApplicationController?

Comment: I am waiting for KM Rakibul synopsis and fix. In terms of your question. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cbmbjdqdzxz582/Screenshot%202015-11-01%2000.54.29.png?dl=0

Comment: OK... btw: that is not the `ApplicationController`, that is the `PinsController`... ;)

Comment: Its been fixed by the genius KM